# How do I show or hide a column in one table when a column in another table is being hovered over?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a webpage showing election results, and I want it to switch from a raw vote map to a percentage map when a percentage is hovered over, using different values for the same key. Changing out the maps is an entirely separate issue, mind, but right now I want to switch out the key labels. The relevant code is currently:

```html
<div id='towninfo'>
  <div id='candidates'>
    <table id='results'>
      <tr>
        <th>Candidate</th>
        <th colspan='2'>Votes</th>
      </tr>
      <tr style='font-weight: bold'>
        <td class='cand' id='cand1'>Candidate 1 &#10004;</td>
        <td class='votes' id='votes1'>100</td>
        <td class='percent' id='pct1'>50%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='cand' id='cand2'>Candidate 2</td>
        <td class='votes' id='votes2'>60</td>
        <td class='percent' id='pct2'>30%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='cand' id='cand3'>Candidate 3</td>
        <td class='votes' id='votes3'>40</td>
        <td class='percent' id='pct3'>20%</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='key'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th class='count'>Votes</th>
      <th class='pctkey'>Percent</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='color' style='background-color: rgb(91, 89, 84);'></td>
      <td class='count'>41-50</td>
      <td class='pctkey'>100%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='color' style='background-color: rgb(120, 114, 99);'></td>
      <td class='count'>31-40</td>
      <td class='pctkey'>75-100%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='color' style='background-color: rgb(164, 151, 122);'></td>
      <td class='count'>21-30</td>
      <td class='pctkey'>50-75%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='color' style='background-color: rgb(200, 186, 153);'></td>
      <td class='count'>11-20</td>
      <td class='pctkey'>25-50%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='color' style='background-color: rgb(223, 216, 197);'></td>
      <td class='count'>1-10</td>
      <td class='pctkey'>0-25%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='color' style='background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);'></td>
      <td class='count'>0</td>
      <td class='pctkey'>0%</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

What I need to do is make it so that, by default, the `pctkey` class is hidden, but when the cursor is over anything in the 'percent' class, the `pctkey` class is shown and the 'count' class is hidden. How do I do this? I already have a `JavaScript` page for displaying the map, so I'm not specifically looking for a `CSS` option.

I tried using `.percent:hover + .pctkey` in the CSS file like various guides have shown, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that in `.pctkey` css class, you have made the `display` property `none`.
Then you can write `Js` code like below:

```
function hideCount(){
     var countElements = document.querySelectorAll(".count");
     var pctElements = document.querySelectorAll(".pctkey");

     for(let i = 0; i<countElements.length; i++)
         countElements[i].style.display = "none"
        
     for(let j = 0; j<pctElements.length; j++)
         pctElements[j].style.display = "table-cell"
 }
    
 function hidePct(){
     var countElements = document.querySelectorAll(".count");
     var pctElements = document.querySelectorAll(".pctkey");

     for(let i = 0; i<countElements.length; i++)
         countElements[i].style.display = "table-cell"
        
     for(let j = 0; j<pctElements.length; j++)
         pctElements[j].style.display = "none"
 }
```

After that, in each one of `td` elements with `percent` class add these two event listeners for `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` events:

`onmouseenter="hideCount()"` and  `onmouseleave="hidePct()"`.

Note that, maybe `#results` table has non-zero `cellspacing` and this will add some space all around the cells and breaks the integrity between `td`s of a column.

You can remove the space (if you want) with:

```
#results{
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I did have to add it in a <script> tag in the HTML file rather than as part of the OpenLayers .js file that I had connected to it, but that proved no issue in the end.

Comment: By the way, if you load the `script` tag just before `</body>`, you can declare `pctElements` and `countElements` variables once and outside the scope of the functions.